# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

Hii guys i am trying to building a music player application then i am getting an error like Cannot read properly split undefined don't know what's going on wrong please try to fix my error

[image]

```
   import axios from "axios";
  
    export const selectRandomKey = () => {
      const keys = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_Keys.split(""); //we are splitting the api keys to make an array
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(keys.length)); //this will get a random number
      return keys[random];
    }
    
    export default axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
      params: {
        part: "snippet",
        videoCategoryId: "10",
        type: "video",
        key: selectRandomKey()
      }
    });
```

Comment: `process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_Keys` console this and check if values are being populated

Comment: having secret keys on the front-end is not advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the `process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_Keys` may be undefined. Instead of directly using split, you can do like
`const YOUTUBE_KEYS = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_Keys || '';` and
`const keys = YOUTUBE_KEYS.split("");`